# Read/Catch stdout message in another application

Tags: java, stdout, stdin, system.out, system.in

I have an application A which writes a stdout message. Now i will build a second application B which reads the stdout from A.

I don't want create a file, the message will be write in the console and should be read from console.

I know, that i have some possibilities to read from console (Scanner, System.console(),  BufferedInputstream), but how can i catch the stdout from another application?

Comment: Are your applications batch applications? Which Operating System do you use?

Comment: No batch application. OS is linux. I need a platform-independent solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try communication through sockets. This guide seems useful http://cs.lmu.edu/~ray/notes/javanetexamples/

Comment: Thx, I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

If your program B executed program A (either through `ProcessBuilder.start()` or `System.exec()`) you have a `Process` instance. Then you can use `Process.getInputStream()` to obtain an input stream which is connected to program A's standard output stream.

Otherwise, there is no platform-independent way to obtain the other program's catch the other program's output. You will need to use some other form of communication.

Comment: Thx for your the note. Unfortunately B is not executed A. What form of communication would you recommend ?